# PHP, MySQL(i) and Dropzone

Tags: php, mysqli, dropzone.js

I am just wondering if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. My goal is pretty simple. Using dropzone or php to upload a file and insert a record into a database. I am able to post the record except for one field which is always showing "array" as the entry. I've tried changing variable names, inserting and removing quotes, etc to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
 Here is my code.

```
    <?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = 'uploads';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "***************";
$dbname = "drop";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO uploads (id, file_name)
VALUES (NULL, 'file_name')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: You've got to test your `move_uploaded_file()` function to ensure it works. Also, you can't use a relative path, you need an absolute path to move the file to. Also, you need to actually set & pass the file name for the file in your query - > `$sql = "INSERT INTO uploads (id, file_name)
VALUES (NULL, 'file_name')";`. You currently just insert `file_name`, not the actual files' name.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So are you saying I should remove the quote from (NULL, 'file_name')?

Comment: The move_uploaded_file() actually does work so I must be missing something.

Comment: No, I'm saying you should actually put the file name in there. How do you get the file name?

Comment: maybe I don't understand your question. I need the name of the file to be represented by a variable. There will be different file names uploaded to the same dbase.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out my own question. The answer is replacing file_name with $targetfile. Now it works as expected. Thanks.